# Iphone - Photoreel from URL Array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, image

I've seen a lot of apps that when you click photos you get a small square of each image, and then when you click them you get a full screen version. Actually, just like the photoreel.

Is there a way of populating the photoreel with an array of images? I have about 6 per location that I'd like to show like that.

I've had a google, but coming up a bit blank!

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [Flikr](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/networking/iphone-json-flickr-tutorial-part-1.html) JSON tutorial (the first part is mostly the JSON calls but they do some early GUI set up too) but it gets a preview of each image in a small thumbnail and then when clicked it opens the full image in the same window.

Depending on how your images are loaded simply replace the json creation with your array/dictionary params and follow how the tutorial progresses, its only 3 parts and has a good starting point for what you're looking for.

Hope it helps

Comment: No problem, let us know how you're getting on and if you're stuck throw up a question, the more code and info you give the better the help